# how to insert bookmark in word using c#/VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-word, bookmarks

I am trying to add bookmarks in word document using C# but it doesn't work and I can't find any help neither in msdn documentation nor on internet. Here is how I am trying to do.

I am reading word documents and then search a keyword in that document and then I convert that text to a hyperlink and that works great. Now, I want to create that text to a bookmark instead of hyperlink. I am doing all this in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Dim _wordApp As ApplicationClass
Dim _doc As Document
Dim pos, len As Integer
Dim reg As Regex
Dim bookmarkName As String
Dim rng As Object
Dim search As String = "Some Text to search"

Dim nullobj As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
Dim isReadOnly As Object = False
_wordApp = New ApplicationClass()

'open the word document
_doc = _wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName, isReadOnly, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, _
     nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, _
     nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj)

    _wordApp.Visible = False


' keyword that you want to search
reg = New Regex(search)
' find the text in word file
Dim m As Match = reg.Match(_doc.Range.Text, 0)
pos = m.Index

' start is the starting position of the token in the content...
len = search.Length
' select the text
rng = _doc.Range(pos, len + pos)

bookmarkName = "MyBookmarkName"
_doc.Bookmarks.Add(bookmarkName, rng)
```

Comment: how to add this bookmark in a specific position(using Left,Right)in word Document?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get to grips with the Open XML SDK. It's not well documented...

I posted some significant time ago about inserting images into Word documents. Not the same thing at all, but you never know, you might find some pointers to get you started...

[HowTo: Insert an image into a Word document and display it using OpenXML](http://hastobe.net/blogs/stevemorgan/archive/2008/09/15/howto-insert-an-image-into-a-word-document-and-display-it-using-openxml.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this but I want to use Word API. The following code crashes my application. The following code works if I add hyperlinks but it does not work if I want to add just the bookmarks. I've commented hyperlink code. 
'_doc.Hyperlinks.Add(_doc.Range(pos, len + pos), Address, _ ' SubAddress, ScreenTip, TextToDisplay, _ ' Target) 
bookmarkName = _doc.Range(pos, len + pos).Text 
Dim rng As Object = _doc.Range(pos, len + pos) 
_doc.Bookmarks.Add(bookmarkName, rng)

Comment: Ok I've got it working. The confusing thing was that it was crashing so there was a bug in .NET API. I noticed that you cannot have spaces in bookmark name. I removed the spaces and now it is working. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Great. I suggest you post your fix as an Answer and then accept it (it's quite alright to answer and accept your own questions) as it will help others experiencing the same problem in the future.