# How to Create a Bookmark in a Word Document using C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm making a C# program that generates a Word file with user inputs and want to make it create bookmarks in the word document.

For example, I have a table at the top of my document that will have a link to various parts of the document later. I want to put a bookmark to the paragraph created by the following code:

```
string actionName = "foo";
Paragraph repairAction = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
repairAction.Range.Text = "1. " + actionName;
repairAction.Range.Bold = 0;
repairAction.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

How would I go about making a bookmark here? And then how would I link to it later?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to insert bookmark in word using c#/VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713289/how-to-insert-bookmark-in-word-using-c-vb-net)

Comment: @TnTinMn Yup, that fixed it. Just had some trouble actually implementing it.